# Save audio files as text tone for Windows Phone Development

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am currently developing an audio app for Windows Phone and I wonder: is it possible to set audio files as a text tone i.e. the sound I get when I receive a text message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do that via API in your application.
But user can change that setting only if he is running GDR3 or above.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I thought anyone who owned a Windows Phone device could change the text tone?

Comment: User can change it in the options page himself, but you app cannot do that.